# Using named vectors instead of positions in square brackets

Tags: r

I am trying to look at how often a certain value appears in a row my data frame.

For that let's look at a a test data frame:

```
df <-
  data.frame(x1 = letters[1:5], x2 = letters[c(1,3,3,1,1)], x3 = letters[c(2,3,3,2,3)])
```

What I did was the following:

```
table(rowSums(df[, 1:3] == "c"))
```

with the output being:

```
0 1 2 3 
2 1 1 1
```

So there are 2 rows in which "c" doesn't appear, one where it appears once, one where it appears twice and one where it appears three times.

I was wondering how one could achieve the same thing without sqare brackets and positional selection (`df[, 1:3]`), but with actual variable names,
so that changing a dataframe doesn't interfere with the results.

I tried multiple versions with `select()`, `pull()` and `filter()` or the %in% but just couldn't get it to work the same way.

Any ideas?

Kind regards, Jakob

Comment: `table(rowSums(df[, c("x1", "x2", "x3")] == "c"))`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it worked that way, too. Thanks alot!